# How to add animation and flash a newly added row to the table while keeping all other row styles as it is?

Tags: css, vue.js, animation, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

I am using the `HTML Table` in my Nuxt 3 or Vue 3-based application and adding a row to it with the click of a button.

When I add a new row I want to add a kind of a `transition/animation` so that the newly added row appears with animation while the rest remains as it is and the newly added row background colour changes to green or some colour for a second so as it flashes to show user it has been newly added. I want to know if it's possible to achieve this using the `tailwind CSS` or need to how to achieve this.

Following is the code I have from my Nuxt 3 or Vue 3 based application:

pages/test.vue:

```
<template>
  <div
    class="py-8 bg-white dark:bg-slate-800 shadow-lg rounded-lg border border-gray-700 p-4 text-black dark:text-white"
  >
    <div class="max-w-screen-lg mx-auto">
      <transition-group name="table-row" tag="div" class="overflow-x-auto">
        <table
          class="w-full table-auto bg-white dark:bg-slate-800 shadow-lg rounded-lg border border-gray-700 text-black dark:text-white"
          key="table"
        >
          <caption></caption>
          <thead key="thead">
            <tr class="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-700">
              <th class="py-2 px-4 font-semibold text-left">ID</th>
              <th class="py-2 px-4 font-semibold text-left">Event</th>
              <th class="py-2 px-4 font-semibold text-left">Options</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody key="t-body">
            <tr
              v-for="row in rows"
              :key="row.ID"
              class="hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
            >
              <td class="py-2 px-4">{{ row.ID }}</td>
              <td class="py-2 px-4">{{ row.Event }}</td>
              <td class="py-2 px-4">
                <button
                  class="hover:ring-slate-200 dark:hover:ring-slate-700 dark:border-slate-700 dark:bg-slate-800 dark:ring-offset-slate-900 flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full border border-slate-300 ring-1 ring-transparent transition-all duration-300 hover:ring-offset-4"
                  @click="handleOptionClick(row)"
                >
                  <span class="justify-center items-center">
                    <Icon
                      icon="ic:round-view-day"
                      width="20"
                      height="20"
                    ></Icon>
                  </span>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button
    @click="addRow"
    class="mt-4 px-4 py-2 text-white bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-green-500 rounded-md"
  >
    Add Row
  </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Icon } from "@iconify/vue";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";

const rowCount = ref(3);

const table = reactive({
  sortable: true,
});

const rows = ref([
  {
    ID: "1",
    Event: "Event 1",
  },
  {
    ID: "2",
    Event: "Event 2",
  },
]);

const addRow = () => {
  const newRow = {
    ID: rowCount.value + 1,
    Event: "RowValue : " + (rowCount.value + 1),
  };
  rows.value.unshift(newRow); // Add the new row to the beginning of the array
  rowCount.value++;

  // Highlight the newly added row with a temporary green background
  newRow.highlighted = true;
  setTimeout(() => {
    newRow.highlighted = false;
  }, 1000); // Remove the highlight after 1 second
};

const handleOptionClick = (row) => {
  console.log("Option button clicked for row:", row);
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Can someone please let me know how to add animation and flash to the newly added row while the rest remains as it is?

Answer (score 0):

This will apply a flashing effect to the whole row with a duration of `1.5s`, `3` times. You just need to add the `highlight` class (through code) to the `tr`:

```
@keyframes new-row {
  from { background-color: red;}
  to { background-color: pink; }
}

#your-table-id {
  tr.highlight td {
    animation: new-row 1.5s 3;
  }
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/n8y2g9c1/